# How can I format a float as a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```py
def main():
    M = float(input('Please enter sales for Monday: '))
    T = float(input('Please enter sales for Tuesday: '))
    W = float(input('Please enter sales for Wednesday: '))
    R = float(input('Please enter sales for Thursday: '))
    F = float(input('Please enter sales for Friday: '))
    sales = [M, T, W, R, F]

        total = 0 

    for value in sales:
        total += value

    print ('The total sales for the week are: $',total('.2f'))

main()
```

With the `.2f` format I am getting this exception:

```py
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

If I remove the `.2f` the script runs properly but the formatting is not how I would like it, it displays as:

```
The total sales for the week are: $ 2500.0
```

I would prefer to have it so that there are 2 decimal places and no space between the $ sign.

Still new to python and learning the basics. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `'{:.2f}'.format(total)`, and to sum a list, use the https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum builtin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
print ('The total sales for the week are: $',total('.2f'))
```

for

```
print ('The total sales for the week are: $',"{0:.2f}".format(total))
```

Comment: Thank you! Used your format statement and removed the comma and the format came out exactly how I was looking for. It now reads: The total sales for the week are: $2500.00

Answer (score 2):

here's a solution using python's 3 f-string feature

```
print (f'The total sales for the week are: {total:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can format strings in a variety of ways. Here are some good resources on them:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html
- https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/
- http://pyformat.info – *(does not include f-string formatting)*

For your case, you can format the total value like this:

```py
>>> total = 1234.56789

>>> "{:.2f}".format(total)
'1234.57'

>>> "%.2f" % total
'1234.57'

# This only works in 3.7 and later
>>> f"{total:.2f}"
'1234.57'
```

For your particular case, you can format the entire `print` string in one go:

```py
print(f"The total sales for the week are: ${total:.2f}")
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you, I can't believe I left it out!

Answer (score 1):

You may total a list with the builtin `sum` function.  Try `print(sum(sales))`.

You may format your floating point like this `print(f'Week is {sum(sales):.2f}')`

Small nits.

Keep Hacking!  Keep notes.

Answer (score 0):

check here [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

sample code

```
def main():
    M = float(input('Please enter sales for Monday: '))
    T = float(input('Please enter sales for Tuesday: '))
    W = float(input('Please enter sales for Wednesday: '))
    R = float(input('Please enter sales for Thursday: '))
    F = float(input('Please enter sales for Friday: '))
    sales = [M, T, W, R, F]

    total = 0 

    for value in sales:
        total += value
    total = "{0:.2f}".format(total)
    print ('The total sales for the week are: $' + str(total))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make this correction:

`print('The total sales for the week are:',format(total,('.2f')),'$')`

Answer (score 0):

Formatters in Python allow you to use curly braces as placeholders for values that you’ll pass through with the `str.format()` method.

As per your requirement

```
total = 0 
print ('The total sales for the week are: $',"{0:.2f}".format(total))
```